# Android Navigation: removing an activity from the backStack

Tags: android, androidx, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation, android-navigation-graph

This question is related specifically to the androidx.navigation library.

I split up my primary graph into 2 graphs because I wanted to have one with a bottom nav with the fragments above it and one without. Instead of using `<include...` I added the activity to the first graph

```
    <activity
        android:id="@+id/Activity2"
        android:name="com...Activity2"
        android:label="Activity2" />
```

This all works nicely, but I also have a splash screen in the first graph that checks if the user is authenticated and navigates them directly into the second graph. With a fragment I can just use the standard `popTo` and `popToInclusive` to manage the fragment backstack but I have not been able to figure out how to do this with two activities so that when the second activity is launched the first is killed and removed from the backstack so the user cannot navigate backwards.

Currently I am just handling it in the fragment where the navigation occurs

```
        navController
            .navigate(R.id.action_someFragment_to_anotherFragment)
        requireActivity().finish()
```

and this works but it leaves room for error and I'd like to deal with it with the navigation library if possible.

Comment: Note that there is a [guide specifically around handling login with Navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-conditional#login). You don't need separate activities to hide a bottom nav on certain destinations since that's precisely the example used for the APIs for [listening for navigation events](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#listen_for_navigation_eventshttps://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#listen_for_navigation_events).

Comment: I'm not sure that guide touches on the problem I'm facing. I have no issue using navigation for bottom nav events. I could probably add a bunch of logic to show/hide the bottom nav using only one activity but that feels hacky and the library supports navigation between activities.

Comment: It supports exiting the scope of one NavController and going to a completely independent activity, yes. That doesn't change how the activity APIs don't allow you to do anything like what you could do in one NavController, as you've found out.

Comment: If the answer is “you can’t” then feel free to answer and I’ll accept it. That was my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each individual `NavController` is totally independent from one another. While an `<activity>` destination allows you to use `navigate()` to go to an entirely separate activity (which may or may not use Navigation itself), Navigation itself will never `finish()` an activity as part of a `navigate()` call so you'd need to do that yourself.

Using multiple activities with different navigation graphs is **not** the recommended way to handle authentication in Navigation as per the the [Navigating Navigation talk](https://youtu.be/09qjn706ITA?t=273) and this approach fails in many ways (such as deep linking and invalidation after process death/recreation) that **are** correctly handled by the [guide for handling login](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-conditional#login). When using one NavController and the [ability to listen for navigation events](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#listen_for_navigation_events), you do not run into these issues.